# Prove that $2^{s(n)} \le d(n) \le 2^{t(n)}$ with given conditions on $d(n)$, $s(n)$ and $t(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors of $n$, $s(n)$ denote the number of prime divisors of $n$ not counting repetitions, and $t(n)$ denote the number of prime divisors of $n$ counting repetitions. We would like to show that $2^{s(n)} \le d(n) \le 2^{t(n)}$ for all positive integers $n$.

For example, if we consider $n=12$, then $d(12)=6$, $s(12)=2$ and $t(12)=3$. Thus $2^{2} \le 6 \le 2^{3}$ is true. If $n$ is prime, then $2^{1} \le 2 \le 2^{1}$.

I'm struggling to come up with a proof for the composite case. I figure that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is required here, but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Hint: $2^s,d,2^t$ are multiplicative functions, that is, if $m,n$ are coprime integers then $(2^s)(m)(2^s)(n)=(2^s)(mn)$. So it’s enough to show the result when $n$ is the power of a prime.

Comment: If I may add a point of view: This is purely combinatorial. Call your primes $p_1,\cdots ,p_k,$ then $s(n)=k$ and $2^{s(n)}$ counts the number of ways you can choose a subset of those primes, multiply them, you get a divisor. This is an injection. The other side is analogous. Let me know if you want details of this.

Answer (score 1):

In fact $s(n)$ and $t(n)$ are known as [prime omega functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function) $\omega(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$. The "definitions" of the functions, for a given $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$, are
$$\omega(n)=k$$
$$\Omega(n)=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_k$$
[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Formulas_at_prime_powers)
$$d(n)=(\alpha_1+1)\cdot(\alpha_2+1)\cdot...\cdot(\alpha_k+1)$$
The easy part is $\alpha_i+1\geq2$ for $i=1..k$, thus
$$d(n)\geq 2^k=2^{\omega(n)}$$
The slightly more complicated (but not too) is to show that $$m+1\leq2^m, \forall m\in \mathbb{N}$$ (**left as an exercise!** e.g. use induction). Then
$$d(n)\leq 2^{\alpha_1}\cdot2^{\alpha_2}\cdot...\cdot2^{\alpha_k}=
2^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_k}=2^{\Omega(n)}$$